# How to send and receive information to/from Excel file having VB macros calculations inside

Tags: vba, vbscript, com

so my case is that I am working with a language(not well known from many) that can work with COM objects (GraphTalk). 
Can I use a COM object to send information to a particular cells in Excel file, then the macros in this Excel file to calculate the result in other specific result cells and then me to get this calculation from these Excell result cells with the COM object again?
If you give me examples with other languages how this can be done with COM object (if a solution exists), then I can try to make it work in my framework.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by myself:

```
Excel = :ole.create_object ("Excel.Application") &
x:Excel.workbooks.open (filename = File) &
Workbook = x:Excel.activeworkbook &
Worksheet = x:Workbook.worksheets ("Sheet_label")

%Get old values for compare reference
Total_old = default (x:Worksheet.range ("G11").value, "") &
Rsrv_old = default (x:Worksheet.range ("C30").value, "") &

%Set new value
x:Worksheet.range ("G11").value = 833000 &
%Refresh all VBScript content
x:Workbook.refreshAll &

%Get new values
Total_new = default (x:Worksheet.range ("G11").value, "") &
Rsrv_new = default (x:Worksheet.range ("C30").value, "") &...
```